# Querying a linked sql server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I added a linked server, which is showing in the linked server list, but when I query it, it throws an error with the db server name.

```
EXEC sp_helpserver
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'aa-db-dev01'
Select * from openquery('aa-db-dev01','Select * from TestDB.dbo.users')
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'aa-db-dev01'.

Answer (score 51):

```
SELECT * FROM [server].[database].[schema].[table]
```

This works for me. SSMS intellisense may still underline this as a syntax error, but it should work if your linked server is configured and your query is otherwise correct.

Comment: From the testing I've done, while 4part naming does work, it ends up being slower than using openquery.

Comment: Also this approach won't work if your table definition contains `xml` column types.

Comment: @Hack-R is the server registered as a linked one?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair It was... now that you mention it, apparently someone deleted it. Thanks.

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK non some -SQL-Server linked servers, resulting in ... An invalid schema or catalog was specified for the provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyLinkedServer".

Comment: @brewmanz thanks for your input, but the question is explicitly tagged with [tag:sql-server], indicating a mssql context. Furthermore, you have to register the server as a linked server.

Comment: @brewmanz furthermore, how should relational-queries work in a non-relational context?!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair A) SQL Server is only *half* of the Linked Server relationship - the server you're directly accessing. The 'other' linked server may or may not be SQL Server, and to announce that the 4-dotted-part is the way to reference it it will leave those who are linking non-SQL Server scratching their heads wondering why it's not working for them
B) I don't understand what non-relational context you are talking about. A linked server can still be relational; it's just that processing a query may not be done completely at the Linked Server location

Answer (score 28):

You need to remove the quote marks from around the name of the linked server. It should be like this:

**Select * from openquery(aa-db-dev01,'Select * from TestDB.dbo.users')**

Comment: You lose intellisense this way so go the other way if you can from a development standpoint but you have to use this way if the provider doesn't expose the catalog or schema.

Comment: With this option, there's an 8000 character limit for the query. Still trying to find a workaround for that. `exec (@Query) at LinkedServerName` seems like a work around for that but I cannot join the result with other tables. Tried using temp tables without luck.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM [aa-db-dev01].[TestDB].[dbo].[users];
```

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK non some -SQL-Server linked servers, resulting in ... An invalid schema or catalog was specified for the provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyLinkedServer".

Answer (score 3):

I use open query to perform this task like so:

```
select top 1 *
INTO [DATABASE_TO_INSERT_INTO].[dbo].[TABLE_TO_SELECT_INTO]
from openquery(
    [LINKED_SERVER_NAME],
    'select * from [DATABASE_ON_LINKED_SERVER].[dbo].[TABLE_TO_SELECT_FROM]'
)
```

The example above uses open query to select data from a database on a linked server into a database of your choosing.

Note: For completeness of reference, you may perform a simple select like so:

```
select top 1 * from openquery(
    [LINKED_SERVER_NAME],
    'select * from [DATABASE_ON_LINKED_SERVER].[dbo].[TABLE_TO_SELECT_FROM]'
)
```

Comment: What could be done if the string has more than 8000 characters (OPENQUERY limitation)?

Comment: Good question - you might want to ask it to the community as I'm not really sure :)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works for me.

Also, in MSSQLMS, you can browse the tree in the Object Explorer to the table you want to query.

[Server] -> Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> [Linked server] -> Catalogs -> [Database] -> [table]

then Right click, Script Table as, SELECT To, New Query Window

And the query will be generated for you with the right FROM, which you can use in your JOIN

Answer (score 2):

try `Select * from openquery("aa-db-dev01",'Select * from users')` ,the database connection should be defined in he linked server configuration

Answer (score 2):

If linked server name is IP address following code is true:

```
select * from [1.2.3.4,1433\MSSQLSERVER].test.dbo.Table1
```

It's just, note [] around IP address section.