# How do I access Linked server Tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have created a Linked server through LAN,

```
Linked server Name-[DELL-PC]
```

Here, I'm not able to run this query to select Values from Linked server

```
case :1
    select *From  [DELL-PC].[BTS_Server].[dbo].Assy_ProductionOrder_ParameterSetting
    select *From  [DELL-PC].[BTS_Server]..Assy_ProductionOrder_ParameterSetting
```

it says:

> "Invalid object name 'BTS_Server.dbo.Assy_ProductionOrder_ParameterSetting'."

but if i use `openquery`, it is working smoothly

```
case :2
    select * 
    From openquery([DELL-PC],
    'Select *From [BTS_Server].[dbo].Assy_ProductionOrder_ParameterSetting ');
```

How do i access linked server Table like case 1 statements, kindly assist me.

Comment: In my case, linked server name contains IP address. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60188969/9117945, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your table contains [XML column](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/247204/tables-with-xml-columns-cannot-be-queried-using-distributed-llinked-server-queries), if yes this syntax won't work.

```
SELECT * FROM [server].[database].[scheme].[table]
```

Possible workarounds:

1. Create view without the XML column(s) on remote server and query that.
2. Use a pass-through query in the form `SELECT * from OPENQUERY (... )`

**Another possible answer:**

Architecture mismatch 32/64-bit when inappropriate `OLE DB Provider` is used:

> 32 bit machines ARE able to query the linked server without using OPENQUERY. It is the 64-bit that must use OPENQUERY

Comment: No, I don't have any xml column in that table, also I have created dummy table with one nvarchar column,it says the same thing.

Comment: In that exception it is not showing the linked server name in prefix of object name.

Comment: @King_Fisher Probably you don't have permissions. See what is set in linked server - security tab and what permission has this user in remote database.

Comment: If I don't have permission, then openquery will not work. Am I right?,  but openquery syntax is working

Comment: Check that I ask and check also default catalog, just expand linked server under SSMS

Comment: I'm not able to check security tab of linked server, it says you can't create a local sql server as linked server, but I hope I have entered correct credentials

Comment: @King_Fisher See http://i.stack.imgur.com/BOrvd.jpg, do you have catalog like screen with your database [BTS_Server]?

Comment: Obviously, yes I have catalogs, and tables, I see all tables

Comment: @King_Fisher Ok, try this `select *From  [DELL-PC].[BTS_Server].[dbo].[Assy_ProductionOrder_ParameterSetting]`

Comment: It says invalid object name 'bts_server.dbo.test123', I'm selecting my test123 table which I have created temporarily.

Comment: @King_Fisher Next thing do you have mismatch between servers 32/64bit?

Comment: Mine is 64 bit,another is 32

Comment: @King_Fisher So you get your answer, as far as I know "32 bit machines ARE able to query the linked server without using OPENQUERY. It is the 64-bit that must use OPENQUERY"

Comment: @King_Fisher Can you try the same in opposite direction?

Comment: @King_Fisher It should work when '32-32', '64-64', '32-64'

Comment: Really, thank you so much,I will check and let u know shorty, thanks again, it helped me

Comment: I have tried with my another machine, mine is 64,new one is 32, but it is working fine here in both directions.

Comment: @King_Fisher So there is problem with `OLE DB provider` which you use to connect, use the same and check if it helps

Comment: Is there any possible of instance name?

Comment: @King_Fisher Do you use Sqlcli11 on both cases? I can't help further without see actual configuration (permission/ole db driver(x64vsx86)/names)

Answer (score 0):

Like below

select * from LinkServername.Databasename.dbo.TableName

But make sure you have valid user and password to access the link server. This is done when you are creating link.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, linked server name contains IP address, so see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60188969/9117945 for more types.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).