# SQL Server OPENQUERY running against master database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, linked-server, openquery

I have the following statement

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,'SELECT * FROM Table')
```

Which is failing with the error

> OLEDB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "MyLinkedServer" returned
>   messages "Deffered prepare could not be completed"

When I try

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,'SELECT DB_NAME()')
```

I can see that the statements are being run against the master database on the linked server.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,'USE MyDB; SELECT * FROM Table')
```

But that also tells me the statement could not be prepared.

How do I control which database on the linked server the OPENQUERY runs against?

The version of SQL server I am running the query on is 2008R2 and the remote server is 2016SP1

Comment: If you are only ever going to use one DB on the remote server, you can set the catalog (Default DB to use) on the Linked server setup. Otherwise see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495719/querying-a-linked-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use three-part name:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,'SELECT * FROM MyDB.schema_name.Table')
```